# Laravel redirect from view to a route

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I want to redirect from a view:

```
Route::get('/MyRoute', function () {
    return View::make('MyView');
});
```

In MyView I want to execute some JavaScript and then Redirect to a download:

```
// some imaginary javascript code, which will get executed

<?php

Redirect::to('/MyRoute2');
```

I can't seem to find a way, which will work. What am I doing wrong?

Of course I could change the `/MyRoute` to:

```
Route::get('/MyRoute', function () {
    return Redirect::to('/MyRoute2');
});
```

but then I can't execute some JavaScript code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use JS for that, inside your view. All php is handled *before* the page renders, so if you want to redirect after some js code you need to call the redirection from the client-side:

```
<script>
// your "Imaginary javascript"
 window.location.href = '{{url("yoururl")}}';
// or
 window.location.href = '{{route("myRoute")}}'; //using a named route
</script>
```

Comment: How can you pass a userid with it?

Comment: @sg_sg94 you can do it using javascript too `window.location.href = '{{url("yoururl")}}'+'/user_id_1';` or instead of `user_id_1` you can again do `{{$user->id}}`

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the Redirect object, just like you must return a View object you must also return the Redirect.

So you will have to `return Redirect::to('/MyRoute2');` in your controller.

Or you could perform the redirect using JS.