# automatically call the route in blade laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

i am new in Laravel, how to call automatically route in blade here is the code in Laravel using laravel 8

```
    @if($activity_type=='General-Activity')
{{ (route('support.direction',$activity_id)) }}
@endif
```

let me explain in Laravelblade i want to check if $activity_type=='General-Activity' route the support.direction and pass a value i use the above code it print only this http://localhost:8000/progress/direction/21c73354-5158-4697-98cb-066800d16e03 i dont know how to route automatically not by click using

Comment: use a `JS` code to automatically redirect user to your route.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580343/laravel-redirect-from-view-to-a-route

Comment: @HassaanAli and Pradeep , thanks for your quick reply, is there any other method to route automatically when the previous page route here, if i use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580343/laravel-redirect-from-view-to-a-route it will more complex the code and logic coz there will be more than 40 conditions in if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're trying to redirect the user automatically if a condition is true. You can use either a `switch` case with `JavaScript` to handle the redirection process. For example. If a URI is `www.example.com/xyz` then get the request by accessing the current page url using `echo url()->current();` This will output the request and use switch case to handle redirection process. For Exapmle here's the sample code for you in Laravel.

```
{{ $url = url()->current(); }}
@switch($url)
    @case('foo')
        First case...
        <script>
        <!-- simulate the script with a mouse click or http redirect -->
        // Simulate a mouse click:
        window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";

        // Simulate an HTTP redirect:
        window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
        </script>
        @break

    @case('baz')
        Second case...
        <script>
        <!-- simulate the script with a mouse click or http redirect -->
        // Simulate a mouse click:
        window.location.href = "http://www.w3schools.com";

        // Simulate an HTTP redirect:
        window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com");
        </script>
        @break

    @default
        Default case...
@endswitch
```